# Scala async { await(...) } in a helper function fails to compile with type mismatch

Tags: scala, asynchronous, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use Scala's `async` and `await` to deal with a future that I am given during a `foldLeft` call, so I write a helper function to do the await as I cannot use `await` inside a nested function:

```
  import scala.await.Await._
  def a(f: Future[T]): T = async {
    await(f)
  }
```

However the above fails with:

```
Error:(33, 38) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[T]
 required: T
      def a(f: Future[T]): T = async {
                            ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are using `scala-async`, its not part of scala core library now. You are actually using `scala.async.Async.{await, async}` but not `scala.await.Await._`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the error says, the return type needs to be `Future[T]`. An async block always returns a future.

[Here](https://github.com/scala/async/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/async/Async.scala) are the signatures of async and await:

```
def async[T](body: T)(implicit execContext: ExecutionContext): Future[T]
def await[T](awaitable: Future[T]): T
```

You can see that `async` is a function of `T => Future[T]`. You might notice this is the same signature as the `Future { ... }` constructor, AKA `Future.apply`. It just constructs a future.

The magic is in `await`. It pulls the value out of the future so you can write "normal" looking code while still dealing with futures.

Comment: My understanding from the Coursera Reactive course is that `async` & `await` on a `Future[T]` yielded `T`...

Comment: It yields the `T` value, but *inside* the `async` block.

Comment: Thanks! This I didn't know!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to await the result of an asynchronous computation, instead of using `await` in an `async` block, you should use [Await.result[T]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$@result[T](awaitable:scala.concurrent.Awaitable[T],atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):T). The `async` block is always returning a `Future`, and you can use the result of an `await` only inside of the async block. Whenever you reuse the awaited value inside the `async` block, it's barely equivalent of using the `onComplete` method of the underlying `Future`.